# Efficient way to search xml node containing node?

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I am working on an XML file with two kinds of nodes (here `foo` and `bar`) at the same level, like this:

```xml
<foo>
    <id>123</id>
    <name>The first foo</name>
</foo>
<foo>
    <id>456</id>
    <name>The second foo</name>
</foo>
<bar>
    <name>The first bar</name>
    <foo>123</foo>
</bar>
<bar>
    <name>The second bar</name>
    <foo>123</foo>
</bar>
```

Note that:

- there is **one** `foo` for each `bar`;
- there are **one or several** `bar` associated to each `foo`.

I would like to get, for each `bar`, the corresponding `foo` node, so I wrote this code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring(data)
for bar in root.findall('bar'):
    for foo in root.findall('foo'):
        if foo.find('id').text == bar.find('foo').text:
            foo_of_bar = foo
            pass
    print bar.find('name').text + ': ' + foo_of_bar.find('name').text
```

result:

```
The first bar: The first foo
The second bar: The first foo
```

But I was asking myself if there is a better way, using the XPath syntax or a more pythonic code.

Comment: what is ET? can you show the imports as well?

Comment: ET for `xml.etree.ElementTree`

Comment: How many nodes are we talking about? A few hundred or a few hundred-thousand?

Comment: A few hundred nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand it correctly, every id will have at least one `foo`, and one or more `bar`s.

So, an efficient way to organize this would be a dictionary like:

```
{
    id: (foo, (bar, bar, ...)),
    id: (foo, (bar, bar, ...)),
    ...
}
```

(Or you can have the foo as the key).

Obviously you have to look for all of the foos to get the first element. From there, you can do a findall for the XPath expression of `bar[foo='{id}']`, which searches for `bar` elements with `foo` childs that have the complete contents between the quotes. So:

```
root = ET.fromstring(data)
foo_bars = {}
for foo in root.findall('foo'):
    foo_id = foo.find('id').text
    bars = tuple(root.findall("bar[foo='{}']".format(foo_id)))
    foo_bars[foo_id] = (foo, bars)
    # Do something with foo (one element),
    # bars (a tuple of elements) and
    # foo_id (A str of the id)

for foo_id, f_bs in foo_bars.items():
    foo, bars = f_bs
    # Also do something
```

This avoids iterating over every foo element for every bar element, as for every foo element, you only iterate over the necessary bar elements.

---

Or, you can iterate over it once and build the dict as you find elements. This will be considerably slower for smaller xml files, but if you have a larger one, it might be faster.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import collections

root = ET.fromstring(data)
foo_bars = collections.defaultdict(lambda: [None, []])
for child in root:
    if child.tag == 'foo':
        # Found a new id
        foo_bars[child.find('id').text][0] = child
    elif child.tag == 'bar':
        foo_bars[child.find('foo').text][1].append(child)
    else:
        # Possibly raise a ValueError?
        pass
for foo_id, f_bs in foo_bars.items():
    foo, bars = f_bs
    # Do something
```